# package(s) for creating knot diagrams

Tags: diagrams

I was wondering if anyone could suggest software/packages to create nice knot diagrams (hopefully with a link to images they have made in the past).

I have used xy-pic recently but am mainly interested in hearing about other options.

Comment: See also `syzygy` module of Asymptote for some specific sorts of knots. http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/drorbn/index.php?title=06-1350/Syzygies_in_Asymptote

Comment: If you're interested in only a few knots, you might want to take a look at the [blue knot gallery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Jim.belk/Image_Gallery#Knot_pictures) of Jim Belk.

Answer (score 38):

I have a prototype package for this using [TikZ/PGF](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).  At the moment, it is a bit basic as it was originally designed to draw very specific link diagrams and only afterwards did I start to extract the more general bits.  Nonetheless, it can produce quite nice knot diagrams (I think) and I'd be happy to hear ideas on how it could be improved.  You can get it from [my homepage](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/HowDidIDoThat/LaTeX/brunnian.html) (when it is a little more polished then I'll put it on CTAN).

Here are some samples to whet your appetite.  First, the preamble for all these examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{brunnian}

\usetikzlibrary{%
  arrows%
}

\tikzset{every path/.style={red,line width=2pt},every node/.style={transform shape,knot crossing,inner sep=1.5pt},>=triangle 60,text node/.style={rectangle,transform shape=false,black}}
```

Next, a trefoil

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \brk in {0,1,2} {
\begin{scope}[rotate=\brk * 120]
\node (k\brk) at (0,-1) {};
\end{scope}
}
\draw (0,0) \foreach \brk in {0,1,2} {let \n0=\brk, \n1={int(Mod(\brk+1,3))}, \n2={int(Mod(\brk+2,3))} in (k\n0) .. controls (k\n0.16 south east) and (k\n1.16 south west) .. (k\n1.center) .. controls (k\n1.4 north east) and (k\n2.4 north west) .. (k\n2)} (k2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: trefoil]

This extends very easily to, for example, a cinquefoil:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \brk in {0,...,4} {
\begin{scope}[rotate=\brk * 72]
\node (k\brk) at (0,-1.5) {};
\end{scope}
}
\draw (0,0) \foreach \brk in {0,...,4} {let \n0=\brk, \n1={int(Mod(\brk+1,5))}, \n2={int(Mod(\brk+2,5))} in (k\n0) .. controls (k\n0.16 south east) and (k\n1.16 south west) .. (k\n1.center) .. controls (k\n1.4 north east) and (k\n2.4 north west) .. (k\n2)} (k2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: cinquefoil]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \brk in {0,...,4} {
\begin{scope}[rotate=-\brk * 72]
\node (k\brk) at (0,-1.5) {};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\brl}{\brk+97}
\node[text node] at (0,2) {\(\char\brl\)};
\end{scope}
}
\node[text node] at (0,0) {\(f\)};
\node[text node] at (126:2.5) {\(g\)};
\draw (0,0) \foreach \brk in {0,...,4} {let \n0=\brk, \n1={int(Mod(\brk-1,5))}, \n2={int(Mod(\brk-2,5))} in (k\n0) .. controls (k\n0.16 south east) and (k\n1.16 south west) .. (k\n1.center) .. controls (k\n1.4 north east) and (k\n2.4 north west) .. (k\n2)} (k2);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

(K)not sure what this one is called, it's an obvious extension of the figure 8 knot:

[image: sort of figure 8ish]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rotate=45] (tl) at (-1,1) {};
\node[rotate=-45] (tr) at (1,1) {};
\edef\twists{10}
\foreach \brk in {0,...,\twists} {
\node (m\brk) at (0,-1 - \brk) {};
}
\foreach \brk in {1,...,\twists} {
\pgfmathparse{int(\brk - 1)}
\edef\brl{\pgfmathresult}
\draw (m\brk) .. controls (m\brk.4 north west) and (m\brl.4 south west) .. (m\brl.center);
\draw (m\brk.center) .. controls (m\brk.4 north east) and (m\brl.4 south east) .. (m\brl);
}
\draw (m0) .. controls (m0.8 north west) and (tl.3 south west) .. (tl.center);
\draw (m0.center) .. controls (m0.8 north east) and (tr.3 south east) .. (tr);
\draw (tl.center) .. controls (tl.16 north east) and (tr.16 north west) .. (tr);
\draw (m\twists) .. controls (m\twists.32 south east) and (tr.32 north east) .. (tr.center);
\draw (m\twists.center) .. controls (m\twists.32 south west) and (tl.32 north west) .. (tl);
\draw (tl) -- (tr.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Also have examples of the Reidemeister moves and likewise.  Most of the images listed at [this nLab page](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SVG+images) were done using this package and then exported to SVG via `tex4ht`.  All of the images at [this page](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/Research/Preprints/TheEnchantedForest/index.html) were done using this package.  In particular, the following monstrosity!

[image: iterated Brunnian link with inscription]

Comment: thanks for the links and nice examples! I think I'll have some fun fiddling around with this

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @chaosflaws This answer is hopelessly out of date.  My newer answer below supersedes this one.

Answer (score 23):

Run with `xelatex` or use package `auto-pst-pdf` or run `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-knot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(5,2)
 \psKnot[linewidth=3pt,linecolor=red](0,0){3-1}
 \psKnot[linewidth=3pt,linecolor=blue](4,0){4-1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The documentation explains the meaning of `3-1` and `4-1`

Comment: The example compiles with xelatex, but no knots in pdf :(

Answer (score 20):

The question is old, so just for the record. MetaPost package [fiziko](https://github.com/jemmybutton/fiziko) may not be the most practical or stable tool for drawing knots, but the images it produces look somewhat fancy. All examples are in ConTeXt, but the same code can be used in LuaLaTeX or standalone as well:

```
\startMPcode
    input fiziko.mp;
    path p;
    p := (dir(90)*4/3cm) {dir(0)} .. tension 3/2 
        .. (dir(90 + 120)*4/3cm){dir(90 + 30)} .. tension 3/2 
        .. (dir(90 - 120)*4/3cm){dir(-90 - 30)} .. tension 3/2 
        .. cycle;
    % p := pathSubdivide(p, 6);
    addStrandToKnot (primeOne) (p, 1/5cm, "l", "1, -1, 1");
    draw knotFromStrands (primeOne);
\stopMPcode
```

[image]

```
\startMPcode
    input fiziko.mp;
    path p;
    p := (0, 2cm) .. (1/2cm, 3/2cm) .. (-1/2cm, 0) .. (1/2cm, -2/3cm) .. (4/3cm, 0) .. (0, 3/2cm) .. (-4/3cm, 0) .. (-1/2cm, -2/3cm) .. (1/2cm, 0) .. (-1/2cm, 3/2cm) .. cycle ;
    % p := pathSubdivide(p, 6) shifted (4cm, -1/2cm);
    addStrandToKnot (primeTwo) (p, 1/6cm, "l", "1, -1, 1, -1, 1");
    draw knotFromStrands (primeTwo);
\stopMPcode
```

[image]

```
\startMPcode
    input fiziko.mp;
    path p[];
    p1 := (fullcircle scaled 2cm) shifted (-1/2cm, 0);
    p2 := p1 shifted (1cm, 0);
    p3 := (-2cm, 0) -- (2cm, 0);
    % p3 := pathSubdivide(p3, 4);
    addStrandToKnot (someKnot) (p1, 1/6cm, "l", "0, 1, 0, 1");
    addStrandToKnot (someKnot) (p2, 1/6cm, "l", "");
    addStrandToKnot (someKnot) (p3, 1/6cm, "l", "1, -1, 1, -1");
    draw knotFromStrands (someKnot);
\stopMPcode
```

[image]

In `addStrandToKnot (primeOne) (p, 1/5cm, "l", "1, -1, 1");`, `primeOne` is the knot name. `p` is a path along which the strand should be drawn (note that `pathSubdivide` thing, the path should contain some reasonable number of points; **upd:** *with recent updates there's no need to subdivide paths for knots in most cases*), `1/5cm` is the strand thickness, `"l"` is the type of shading (can be `"l"`, `"t"` or `"e"`, the latter is simply empty outline which works much faster and `"t"` doesn't work very well for now) and `"1, -1, 1"` is a list of "layers" where intersections in order of appearance along the path, go (above default "zero" level or below it).

And `knotFromStrands (primeOne)` actually draws all the strands and returns a picture.

Upd:

Default shading settings have been changed since the images above were produced and the output would look somewhat different now. These settings can be altered with `defineMinStrokeWidth` macro, which determines shading stroke width (default is `1/5pt`) and `defineLightDirection`, which determines where does "light" come from (default is `-1/8pi, 1/8pi`). For instance, first knot with

```
defineLightDirection(1/8pi, -1/6pi);
defineMinStrokeWidth(1/5pt);
```

would look like this:

[image]

Comment: That looks pretty nice!

Comment: Can you add an option to for basic knot drawing (with plain indication above or below)

Comment: I think i can, but could you provide an example of what you want to have?

Comment: This is looking great! I have never used "startMPcode", and I get an "undefined control sequence" with pdflatex. Do you know how I can use it without changing to LuaLatex?

Comment: is it possible to have a path "split" in two, like in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555119/how-to-draw-a-non-planar-shape-in-tikz?noredirect=1#comment1401323_555119)?

Comment: @Jxx Thank you! Initially, i did use pdflatex with `emp` package to include metapost code directly into the document. Eventually, it stopped working and I tried `gmp` https://ctan.org/pkg/gmp , it did work similarly, but it was slow and I switched to LuaLaTeX, but now I can't get `gmp` to do its thing. You can try it, maybe it's just my setup. I'll try and find a way to make it work and, in case of success, will follow up here.

Comment: @Jxx Branching is a feature i really want to include, but i didn't find a reasonable solution to the problem of the user interface for this. How would one conveniently describe a branching structure? Otherwise, it's doable and may be implemented in the future.

Comment: @SergeySlyusarev Yes it is not so easy to do it in an automated way. I have started drawing some in Photoshop, and there I just put a few shadings on the corners of the branching, but not much. Of course the best would be to have the edges slightly rounded, which probably makes it more difficult.

Answer (score 15):

(This question, although old, keeps coming up when I search for `tikz knots` - yes, I know I'm searching for my own package but it's how I find the documentation when I'm on a foreign machine - so I thought I'd add an answer about the tikz knots library which was developed some time after this question was asked.)

There's a TikZ library, `knots`, which is available on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/spath3) (as part of a package called `spath3`) and [github](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3).  There are quite a few questions on this site with examples using this package, here are just a few:

- [Braid diagrams in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32125/86) which inspired the original version.
- [problem with "crop circles" in tikz knot library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188447/86) which let to an improvement, and also the spin-off package [celtic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/celtic) specifically for celtic-style knots
- [Crossings not appearing for small knots drawn using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/217719/86)
- [Draw string with linking numbers or no linking number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167704/86)

Answer (score 2):

(The interface just asked me "Are you sure you want to add *yet another* answer?")

The [`spath3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) (which the `knots` library is actually part of) has now been extended with a new set of routines that are useful in drawing knots.  These work by actually cutting a path at the points where it intersects with another path and inserting gaps at those points, so it is particularly suited to situations where there is a non-uniform background, or where the aim is to style different pieces of the diagram differently (for example to illustrate a 3-colouring).

Here's a trefoil example.  For more examples, see the documentation (`texdoc spath3`) or look on [github](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17181/86}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3, intersections, hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  use Hobby shortcut,
  every trefoil component/.style={ultra thick, draw, red},
  trefoil component 1/.style={blue},
]
\path[spath/save=trefoil] ([closed]90:2) foreach \k in {1,...,3} { .. (-30+\k*240:.5) .. (90+\k*240:2) } (90:2);
\tikzset{spath/knot={trefoil}{8pt}{1,3,5}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: trefoil with one component blue]