# Draw string with linking numbers or no linking number?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikzlibrary

How can I use LaTex (p.s. I use Mac OS 10.5.8 with TexShop 2.47) to draw strings with linking numbers or no linking numbers?

If any experts know any examples below, please feel free to comment. The answer needs not to completely solve everything.

Here are the three examples:

Fig. 1. No Link:

[image]

Fig. 2. Link = 1:

[image]

Fig. 3. Link = 2:

[image]

Fig. 4. Borromean Ring:

[image]

Comment: Please the answer can be as simple as possible, using tikz alone without unnecessary package is the best. Thank you.

Comment: Please take a look at the [`knots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/spath3) library for TikZ.

Comment: I also found another helpful weblink: http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2013/04/how-can-i-draw-a-knot-in-tex-let-me-count-the-ways/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example of using the `knots` library as per  Gonzalo Medina's suggestion:

[image]

If you comment out the `draft mode=crossings` you can see how the crossings are numbered, and then you use `flip crossing=<num>` to toggle each of the intersections.

### Procedure:

For the other drawing it is just a matter of first `\draw`ing the lines (which is independent of using the `knots` library. Then

1. Move the code into the `knot` environment,
2. Change the `\draw` to a `\strand`,
3. Add the option `draft mode=crossings` to get the crossings numbered,
4. Use `flip crossing` as desired to get the crossing at the appropriate "level", and
5. Remove the `draft mode=crossings`.

Note that I used a `circle` shape but any arbitrary shape should work.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{knot}[
    %draft mode=crossings ,
    clip width=3,
    flip crossing=1,
    flip crossing=2,
    ]
    \strand [ultra thick, red  ] (0,0) circle (1.0cm);
    \strand [ultra thick, black] (1,0) circle (1.0cm);
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace*{0.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{knot}[
    %draft mode=crossings ,
    clip width=3,
    flip crossing={2},
    ]
    \strand [ultra thick, red  ] (0,0) circle (1.0cm);
    \strand [ultra thick, black] (1,0) circle (1.0cm);
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{knot}[
    %draft mode=crossings ,
    clip width=4,
    ]
    \strand [ultra thick, blue ] (0,0) circle (1.0cm);
    \strand [ultra thick, red  ] (1,0) circle (1.0cm);
    \strand [ultra thick, green] (0.5,1) circle (1.0cm);
    \flipcrossings{1, 2, 5, 6}
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Peter, thanks for the nice comment, let me try it. :-)