# Knot package: crossings lost again

Tags: tikz-pgf

Basically I have the same problem as someone else in the question [Crossings not appearing for small knots drawn using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217719/drawing-knots-with-tikz-no-visible-crossings).

I wanted to make a knot smaller and have thicker lines (thick or very thick): My result is visible on the left side of the picture. On the right the crossings are fine and as they should be. I played around with `end tolerance=1pt` and `ignore endpoint intersections=false`, but it does not work so far.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.shapes,decorations.markings,knots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (-1.2,-2.2)--(1.7,2.2);
\begin{knot}[
scale=0.8,
draft mode=crossings,
consider self intersections=true,
clip  width=1,
flip crossing=6,
flip crossing=4,
flip crossing=7,
flip crossing=2,
line width=2pt,
onlywhenrendering/.style={
    draw=white,
    double=black,
    doubledistance=6pt,
    linecap=round,
},
]
\strand
(-1,0) to[out=90,in=180,looseness=1]
(0,0.5) to[out=0,in=90,looseness=1]
(1.5,-0.5) to[out=-90,in=0,looseness=1] 
(1,-1) --
(-1,-1) to [out=180,in=180,looseness=1]
(-1,1.5) to [out=0,in=90,looseness=1]
(0.5,0.5) --(0.5,-1) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=2.9]
(-0.5,-1)--(-0.5,0.5) to[out=90,in=180,looseness=1]
(1,1.5)to[out=0,in=90,looseness=1]
(1.5,0.5)to[out=-90,in=0,looseness=1]
(0,-0.5) to[out=180,in=-90,looseness=1]
(-1,0)
;
\end{knot}
\draw (0,-2.4) node{$8_{17}$};
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\begin{knot}[
consider self intersections=true,
clip  width=2,
flip crossing=1,
flip crossing=3,
flip crossing=5,
flip crossing=8,
]
\strand
(-1,0) to[out=90,in=180,looseness=1]
(0,0.5) to[out=0,in=90,looseness=1]
(1.5,-0.5) to[out=-90,in=0,looseness=1] 
(1,-1.5) --
(-1,-1.5) to [out=180,in=180,looseness=1]
(-1,2) to [out=0,in=90,looseness=1]
(0.5,1) --(0.5,-1) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=2.9]
(-0.5,-1)--(-0.5,1) to[out=90,in=180,looseness=1]
(1,2)to[out=0,in=90,looseness=1]
(1.5,0.5)to[out=-90,in=0,looseness=1]
(0,-0.5) to[out=180,in=-90,looseness=1]
(-1,0)
;
\end{knot}
\draw (0,-2.4) node{Mirror image of $8_{17}$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this is still a relevant question, but here goes with an answer anyway.  I'm sorry that I didn't spot this question before (I'm not as active here as I used to be).

Anyway, there are a few issues with your code.  One is the disregard for spaces!  They're quite important.  So I've fixed them.

Then there's the `line cap=round`.  This was doing weird things at the start-end point of your knot.  So that's gone, too.

The main thing was that all crossings were very close to end points of segments in your strand.  So you needed `ignore endpoint intersections=false`.  The `end tolerance` key doesn't seem to make a difference in your picture, but because your crossings are very close together then the clip radius and clip width have to be carefully set.

Here's what I ended up with after a bit of playing with the numbers.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241258/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.shapes,decorations.markings,knots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (-1.2,-2.2)--(1.7,2.2);
\begin{knot}[
scale=0.8,
%draft mode=crossings,
  consider self intersections=true,
  ignore endpoint intersections=false,
%end tolerance=1pt,
clip radius=8pt,
clip width=1,
flip crossing=6,
flip crossing=4,
flip crossing=7,
flip crossing=2,
line width=2pt,
only when rendering/.style={
  white,
  double=black,
  double distance=6pt,
},
]
\strand
(-1,0) to[out=90,in=180,looseness=1]
(0,0.5) to[out=0,in=90,looseness=1]
(1.5,-0.5) to[out=-90,in=0,looseness=1] 
(1,-1) --
(-1,-1) to [out=180,in=180,looseness=1]
(-1,1.5) to [out=0,in=90,looseness=1]
(0.5,0.5) --(0.5,-1) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=2.9]
(-0.5,-1)--(-0.5,0.5) to[out=90,in=180,looseness=1]
(1,1.5)to[out=0,in=90,looseness=1]
(1.5,0.5)to[out=-90,in=0,looseness=1]
(0,-0.5) to[out=180,in=-90,looseness=1]
(-1,0)
;
\end{knot}
\draw (0,-2.4) node{$8_{17}$};
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\begin{knot}[
consider self intersections=true,
clip width=2,
flip crossing=1,
flip crossing=3,
flip crossing=5,
flip crossing=8,
]
\strand
(-1,0) to[out=90,in=180,looseness=1]
(0,0.5) to[out=0,in=90,looseness=1]
(1.5,-0.5) to[out=-90,in=0,looseness=1] 
(1,-1.5) --
(-1,-1.5) to [out=180,in=180,looseness=1]
(-1,2) to [out=0,in=90,looseness=1]
(0.5,1) --(0.5,-1) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=2.9]
(-0.5,-1)--(-0.5,1) to[out=90,in=180,looseness=1]
(1,2)to[out=0,in=90,looseness=1]
(1.5,0.5)to[out=-90,in=0,looseness=1]
(0,-0.5) to[out=180,in=-90,looseness=1]
(-1,0)
;
\end{knot}
\draw (0,-2.4) node{Mirror image of $8_{17}$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: Knots]