# Using TikZ, how to draw planes non simple curves (self-intersecting curves)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can't draw planes simple curves (other than circles or ellipses), closed as these
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17181/packages-for-creating-knot-diagrams

Comment: Excuse me, I think the curves drawn there are curves in spaces

Comment: @Andrew I'd say no: knots and curves are not the same thing.

Comment: In Metapost the first one is as simple as `drawarrow origin {left} .. 34 down {right} .. 10 up .. 21 down .. cycle;`  Can you do something like that in TikZ with the `hobby` package?

Comment: @Thruston Yes. Posted an answer with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it was suggested to you in the comments, you can use the `hobby` Tikz library and use the option `[closed hobby]` in the draw options. Notice that it follows the same syntax of a plot by using coordinates (it *is* a plot, after all).

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[closed hobby] plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (0,1) (.5,.3) (.5,.7) (0,0)};

\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\draw[closed hobby] plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,0) (2,1)};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```