# Tikz package. Trefoil.

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to plot a trefoil like this in Tikzpicture?  [image]

Comment: What have you done so far, to draw this picture? It is quite unlikely, that people are willing to help you, if you showed no effort to solve your problem. This is a plattform for learning Tex not for outsourcing your work.

Comment: Do you have parametric equations for it at least? See if section 22.5 *Plotting a function* in `pgfmanual.pdf` helps.

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17181/packages-for-creating-knot-diagrams

Comment: This is the fourth picture you've outsourced. How many do you have to go? I understand that you might have initially had no idea how to even start, but you can presumably at least begin by setting up the basic document and `tikzpicture` environment now. Or, if not, then the answers provided to your other questions have not been of much help to you.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  Yes!  Cos[t]^2 (-1 + 4 Sin[t]^2), Cos[t] Sin[t] (-1 + 4 Sin[t]^2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I alluded to, you basically only have to copy an example from section 22.5 in the manual for TikZ and replace the equations with the ones you want. In the first example note that the `r` indicates that radians should be used, by default the trigonometric functions in `pgf` uses degrees.

I also added an example with `pgfplots`, which is convenient if you need axes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} % also loads tikz
\begin{document}              
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[domain=0:pi,variable=\t,samples=200]
plot ({cos(\t r)^2*(-1 + 4*sin(\t r)^2)},{cos(\t r)*sin(\t r)*(-1 + 4*sin(\t r)^2)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  trig format=rad,
  domain=0:pi,
  samples=200,
  width=4cm,
  axis equal]
\addplot [black] ({cos(x)^2*(-1 + 4*sin(x)^2)},{cos(x)*sin(x)*(-1 + 4*sin(x)^2)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem is that I can't figure out why  the package  pgfplots  '' is not found ''..

Comment: @AndreaLeo Because it's not installed presumably. Anyway, if all you need is the trefoil itself, use the first example, and replace `pgfplots` with `tikz`.