# How to draw a non-planar shape in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

What is the easiest way to draw something like that in Tikz?

[image]

I think it is doable with controls, but it is not very efficient nor precise. Is there something more adapted?

Comment: What do you mean by *precision*? The drawing you are showing does not have straight lines but curved lines for example.

Comment: This is possible with the `knots` package *(part of spath3)* here:[The knots Package](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3)

Comment: @manooooh Yes, the problem that I can see would be the non-planar part (where one "channel" goes below another), where the lines should seem continuous. This is not so easy to do with controls.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but here is a simple approach in [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html) just in case it was useful to anyone.  Making the lines with random widths is a bit hard, but doing the cross-over is easy just by over-drawing the part where the path crosses over.

[image]

Here I have slightly cheated because I *know* that the path must cross at the origin.  For a more general approach you could calculate the intersection points using `intersectiontimes` and `subpath` sections of your loop.

Compile this with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
path foo, bar, baz; 
foo = (origin .. up {right} .. tension 3/2 .. down {right} .. cycle) xscaled 42 yscaled 18;
bar = point 1/4 of foo {direction 1/4 of foo rotated 90} .. point 13/8 of foo;
baz = bar & subpath (13/8, 37/8) of foo;

draw baz withpen pencircle scaled 3;
undraw baz withpen pencircle scaled 2;

interim linecap := butt;
draw   subpath (-1/8, 1/8) of foo withpen pencircle scaled 3;
interim linecap := rounded;
undraw subpath (-1/8, 1/8) of foo withpen pencircle scaled 2;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For comparison, here is a pure `TikZ` solution using `double`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\draw[double distance=3pt, looseness=3](-.5,.5)--(-1,1)to[out=135,in=45](1,1)--(-1,-1)to[out=225,in=-45](1,-1)--(.5,-.5)
    (-.75,-.75){[looseness=1]to[out=135,in=225](-.75,.75)};
\draw[double distance=3pt] (-.5,.5)--(.5,-.5); % overcross
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a small trick in your code: the overcrossing is a straight segment. However, your solution works fine in this situation

Comment: @BlackMild: Yes. Of course if you wanted the overcrossing to be on a curved segment it is easy to match the angles at the endpoints for a smooth join.